# SQL Server "Insert into Execute at linked server" sometimes affects 0 rows

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linked-server

I am trying to execute a select query on a linked MySQL server and insert the results in a table on the current SQL Server. The problem is that sometimes nothing gets inserted, even when it should.

```
declare @CurrentDate date = getdate()
declare @NextDate date = dateadd(d, 1, @CurrentDate)

declare @Sql nvarchar(max) = 
        'select 
            CustomerCode,
            InvoiceDate,
            ProductCode,
            Value
        from Invoices
        where InvoiceDate between ''' + convert(nchar(10), @CurrentDate, 120) + ''' and ''' + convert(nchar(10), @NextDate, 120) + ''''

declare @SqlLimit1 nvarchar(max) = @Sql + ' limit 1'

exec (@SqlLimit1) at [srv]
declare @RowsExist bit = cast(@@rowcount as bit)

insert into Invoices(CustomerCode, InvoiceDate, ProductCode, Value)
exec (@SqlLimit) at [srv]
declare @RowsAffected bit = @@rowcount
```

For clarity, here is the printed version of the 2 strings (using today as the current date):

```
-- @SqlLimit1:
select 
            CustomerCode,
            InvoiceDate,
            ProductCode,
            Value
        from Invoices
        where InvoiceDate between '2021-02-24' and '2021-02-25' limit 1
```

```
-- @Sql:
select 
            CustomerCode,
            InvoiceDate,
            ProductCode,
            Value
        from Invoices
        where InvoiceDate between '2021-02-24' and '2021-02-25'
```

After running the script with today's date, `@RowsExist` should be 1 and `@RowsAffected` should be ~20000. However, if I run the script repeatedly, in some of the runs, nothing is inserted (i.e. `@RowsAffected` is 0), even though it should be (`@RowsExist` is 1 in 100% of the runs). So it either inserts all ~20000 rows, or none at all. The script finishes running succesfully 100% of the runs; no error gets thrown.

System Information:

- SQL Server: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)
- Linked server ([srv]) uses MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver

Comment: What happens if you try it with `OPENQUERY`? Also, if it's a linked server, why don't you just do a standard non-dynamic `SELECT`

Comment: I used `OPENQUERY` originally, but I started getting the following error
`Cannot process the object.The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object`.
```